As a subject, does "What I said and what I did" govern a singular verb or a plural one following it?
What is the  subject–verb agreement for this seven-word subject?

What I said and what I did _________.

Should that subject then be followed by singular or plural verb?

Welcome to ELU.  Could you say a bit more about how this question is problematic, and indicate what steps you have taken to find an answer yourself?

@Tuffy She gave the subject. Imagine the verb is be: in what cases might the subject she gave take is, and in what cases might it take are?

Who is 'she'? What I said and what I did are two different things.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@KateBunting She's our asker, Edith.

A double word subject: A and B are [whatever]

@Lambie The ship's master and commander was unwilling to delay further. Now stop answering in comments.

Both are possible but mean different things:

What I said and what I did was wait for the postman.

What he said and what he did are two different things.



Prezackerly so.
